# With statement select and function into cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, with-statement

it is possible to use the with structure with a function inside a cursor, I don't know if I am declaring it inappropriately, I am getting the following error `using with function inside procedure pl sql statement is not supported`

```
CURSOR c_detail IS
WITH 
FUNCTION CALC_NUMBER(FOB_ITEM    NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
                     FOB_TOTAL   NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
                     WEIGHT NUMBER DEFAULT 0) RETURN NUMBER
     IS
     PESO_BRUTO_ITEM NUMBER :=0;
     BEGIN
         IF( (FOB_ITEM > 0) AND (FOB_TOTAL > 0 AND WEIGHT> 0 )) THEN
             PESO_BRUTO_ITEM := (FOB_ITEM * WEIGHT) / FOB_TOTAL;
         END IF;
         RETURN PESO_BRUTO_ITEM;
END CALC_NUMBER;  
test_data AS
(
SELECT 36.25 AS FOB_I, 12536.36 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 15.36 AS FOB_I, 3678.65 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 878.77 AS FOB_I, 89653.13 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual
)
SELECT TD.FOB_I,
       TD.FOB_TOTAL,
       CALC_NUMBER(TD.FOB_I, TD.FOB_TOTAL, TD.W) WEIGHT
  FROM test_data TD
```

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Based on this (https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#plsql-support), I believe you'd need to use dynamic SQL in order to accomplish this

Comment: @M10 Oracle 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR] You can declare a function in a sub-query factoring clause but (as Justin Cave [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295124/with-statement-select-and-function-into-cursor/59295480#comment104794978_59295124)) it only works when you are executing the query as dynamic SQL and support for using functions in static SQL within a cursor may be available in future database versions.

---

This sub-query factoring clause with a function works outside of a cursor:

```sql
WITH
  FUNCTION with_function(
    p_id IN NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 42 + p_id;
  END;
test_data ( id ) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 
)
SELECT id,
       with_function( id )
FROM   test_data;
```

Trying to put it into a cursor (in Oracle 18c):

```sql
DECLARE
  p_id NUMBER;
  p_fn NUMBER;

  CURSOR c_detail IS
  WITH
    FUNCTION with_function(
      p_id IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN 42 + p_id;
    END;
  test_data ( id ) AS (
    SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 
  )
  SELECT id,
         with_function( id )
  FROM   test_data;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_detail;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_detail INTO p_id, p_fn;
    EXIT WHEN c_detail%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_id || ', ' || p_fn );
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c_detail;
END;
/
```

Outputs the error:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 7, column 14:
> PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
> ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> ORA-06550: line 13, column 5:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
>    exists prior
> ```

Removing the function then the cursor works:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_id NUMBER;

  CURSOR c_detail IS
  WITH
  test_data ( id ) AS (
    SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 
  )
  SELECT id
  FROM   test_data;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_detail;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_detail INTO p_id;
    EXIT WHEN c_detail%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_id );
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c_detail;
END;
/
```

So it is not an issue with using a sub-query factoring clause in a cursor.

Executing the cursor as dynamic SQL query:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_id NUMBER;
  p_fn NUMBER;
  c_detail SYS_REFCURSOR;

  p_sql VARCHAR2(4000) := 'WITH
    FUNCTION with_function(
      p_id IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN 42 + p_id;
    END;
  test_data ( id ) AS (
    SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 
  )
  SELECT id,
         with_function( id )
  FROM   test_data';
BEGIN
  OPEN c_detail FOR p_sql;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_detail INTO p_id, p_fn;
    EXIT WHEN c_detail%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_id || ', ' || p_fn );
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c_detail;
END;
/
```

Works and outputs:

> ```
> 1, 43
> 2, 44
> 3, 45
> ```

So it appears that, yes, you can declare a function in a sub-query factoring clause but it only works when you are executing the query as dynamic SQL.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca5d63a6846d918981bced53e214816a)*

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I thought it was me who is declaring something wrong at the cursor

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says you can't do what you are after, but then you will not have to if your cursor looks like following

```
CURSOR c_detail IS
WITH test_data AS(
    SELECT 36.25 AS FOB_I, 12536.36 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 15.36 AS FOB_I, 3678.65 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 878.77 AS FOB_I, 89653.13 AS FOB_TOTAL, 362 AS W FROM dual
)
SELECT TD.FOB_I,
       TD.FOB_TOTAL,
       CASE WHEN TD.FOB_I > 0 AND TD.FOB_TOTAL > 0 AND TD.W > 0 
       THEN (TD.FOB_I * TD.W) / TD.FOB_TOTAL
       ELSE 0
       END WEIGHT
FROM test_data TD
;
```